# (C#) Array not beeing populated

Tags: c#, arrays

I am dealing with some issues regarding arrays and more specifically the array index. I sometimes get this error. Its really random when it will occur. I am fairly new to c# and haven't used arrays almost never.

The error message is:

```
Exception type: System.IndexOutOfRangeException
Exception message: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
```

I would assume the array isn't getting populated but if that's the case how can I check it? and how can I fix it?
And it happens on this line:

```
Game.DisplayNotification("fc", "ems", "~g~Medical ID Card~w~", personaForPed.FullName, 
    "~g~Patient ID: ~w~" + personaForPed.PatientID + "\n~g~Sex: ~w~" + 
    personaForPed.Gender.ToString() + "\n~g~Birth Date: ~w~" + 
    personaForPed.Birthday.ToShortDateString() + "\n~y~Allergies: ~w~" + 
    personaForPed.Allergies[1] + "\n~y~Conditions: ~w~" + personaForPed.Conditions[1] + 
    "\n~g~Blood Type: ~w~" + Persona.GetBloodTypeName(personaForPed.BloodType));
```

Obviously I know what the error is but I cant find out why this is happening. The [x] when I call  `personaForPed.Allergies[x]`
should be the int amount in the `GetAllergies(int amount)` or more like the boundaries of the array like from 0 to 19 ( as my array has 20 strings)?

```
public string[] Allergies
        {
            get;
        }
```

and then

```
public static string[] GetAllergies(int amount)
{
    string[] array = new string[20]
    {
        // Array is populated here
    };

    Common.Random.Shuffle(array);
    return array.Take(amount).ToArray();
}
```

And here is the Persona basically `Persona personaForPed = Persona.GetPersonaForPed(closestPed);`

```
public static Persona GetPersonaForPed(Ped ped)
{
    Ped = ped;
    Persona persona = null;

    if (PersonaDictionary.ContainsKey(ped))
    {
        PersonaDictionary.TryGetValue(ped, out Persona value);

        if (value != null)
        {
            persona = value;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        string[] array = GetName(ped).Split(' ');
        persona = new Persona(ped, array[0], array[1], 
            GetAllergies(Common.Random.Next(1, 4)), 
            GetConditions(Common.Random.Next(1, 4)), 
            GetPatientID(), GetBirthday(ped), GetGender(ped), GetAge(ped), 
            GetBloodType(ped));
        PersonaDictionary.Add(ped, persona);
    }

    return persona;
}
```

Comment: If `array` has one item, then `array[1]` will fail with that error. Which line specifically is causing the issue?

Comment: Where exactl<does the exception occur? I can´t see any index-based array-access in the above code (except `array[0]` and `array[1]`).

Comment: Where are you accessing the array returned by GetAllergies? are you accessing an array property on the Persona (thats assigned in the constructor by GetAllergies())?

Comment: @HimBromBeere The error happens on this line                                 `Game.DisplayNotification("fc", "ems", "~g~Medical ID Card~w~", personaForPed.FullName, "~g~Patient ID: ~w~" + personaForPed.PatientID + "\n~g~Sex: ~w~" + personaForPed.Gender.ToString() + "\n~g~Birth Date: ~w~" + personaForPed.Birthday.ToShortDateString() + "\n~y~Allergies: ~w~" + personaForPed.Allergies[1]  + "\n~y~Conditions: ~w~" + personaForPed.Conditions[1] + "\n~g~Blood Type: ~w~" + Persona.GetBloodTypeName(personaForPed.BloodType));`

Comment: @RufusL The array has 20 items

Comment: @CoryMelendez The `GetAllergies()` is processed on `persona = new Persona(…)`

Comment: I'm talking abougt *this* array: `string[] array = GetName(ped).Split(' ');`

Comment: `personaForPed.Allergies` does not contain 20 elements, but to 1 to 4. So chances are `personaForPed.Allergies[1]` throws because the array has only a single element.

Comment: Strange that you didn't include the line of code that was throwing the exception in the question. Clearly one of the arrays that you're accessing by the index does not have that many items. Either `personaForPed.Allergies[1]` or `personaForPed.Conditions[1]` based on the code sample in the comment above. Set a breakpiont and step through the code to examine the values. Also, you might want to split out that long string concatenation into separate lines before the `DisplayNotification` call so you can validate the items being added to the string.

Comment: @RufusL They have both 20 items for example   `public static string[] GetAllergies(int amount)
  {
   string[] allergiesarray = new string[20]
   {
   "~w~Egg",
   "~w~Milk",
etc
   };
   Common.Random.Shuffle(allergiesarray);
   return allergiesarray.Take(amount).ToArray();
  }`

Comment: If that line is causing the exception, then one of them doesn't have 20 items. You need to debug the code since we can't see the current state of `personaForPed` from the sample given. Set a breakpoint and examine `personaForPed` in the debugger.

Comment: `return allergiesarray.Take(amount).ToArray()` just returns `amount` number of items, not 20. Thus `Persona.Allergies` only countains those items...

Comment: @HimBromBeere So how I should do it instead? just a return?

Comment: That depends, should your person have 20 allergies or just 1-4 random ones?

Comment: @HimBromBeere one to three random as you said

Comment: As arrays are zero-based, `myArray[1]` may throw when only a single item is in `myArray`. So you should check the length of the array before aaccessing.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Thanks for these clarifications. One question thought. myArray[1] will not return only the first item am I correct? But I guess it will show only one item?

Comment: @RufusL, @himbrombeere By the way here is how I define the string  is there an issue with that?                                `public string[] Allergies
        {
            get;
        }`
and then 
`public static string[] GetAllergies(int amount)
        {
            string[] allergiesarray = new string[20]
            {
            "~w~Egg",
            "~w~Milk",
              ......
            };
            Common.Random.Shuffle(allergiesarray);
            return allergiesarray.Take(amount).ToArray();
        }`

Comment: `myArray[1]` returns the second item. Arrays are zero-based in c#. `myArray[0]` returns the first item.

Comment: @RufusL yes I know that now the issue that I am thinking is that the array is not getting populated. I updated the question as well. Why could that happen? Is there a better way of creating the string array?

Comment: Why don't you set a breakpoint and step through your code so you can see what's going on?

Comment: @RufusL I tried that but the game process would crash with interactive debugging